# Selenium inserting random letters from password

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a bot using Selenium which will log in to my back accountand download incomes and outcomes and generate raports. I am stuck with logging in as for the first time I need to insert just randomly choosen letters from my password instead of putting in whole. So far my code, is not existing as I want to log in first before I start writting next features.

```
class BankAccountLogin():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    def login(self, login, password):
        self.driver.get("https://system.aliorbank.pl/sign-in")
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("login").send_keys(login, "\n")

    bank_app = BankAccountLogin()
    bank_app.login(login, password)
```

Password area looks like this and it's chaning after every log in attempt.
[image]

HTML5 coding of this page looks like this:

- for uneditable fields in this case field No 1:
  [image]
- for editable field where I am supose to inter letter in this case No 2:
  [image]

I tried looking for help everywhere online bu  couldn't find anyone trying to solve this issue. Trying to refer to that password letter areas as to

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']").send_keys("x")
```

resulted with Error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: Do not share images of code. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you query by type password, looks like that doesn't change?

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']").send_keys("")
```

EDIT
the code above will return a list of obj because from your HTML code, there is a bunch of elements that use type password.

```
 import random
 list_obj = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']")
 passwords = ["psswd", "psswd2"]
 for element in list_obj:
    element.send_keys(random.choice(passwords))
```

OR if the first element you want

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']")[0].send_keys("")
```

I don't really understand what you want to do, but I hope this helps you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: While trying this I got:
self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='password']").send_keys("X")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: Should be `self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='password']")[0].send_keys("X")` since `driver.find_elements` is a `List` object

or 
`self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']").send_keys("X")`